# Arguments, Parameters, and Where They Go -- How to Use the Terms

Tags: parameters, arguments, parameter-passing, parentheses

A question that has long bothered me is what to call the area between parentheses in function calls and the like -- the spot where arguments go or parameters are declared. I've seen these in almost every language I've worked with -- certainly every functional language -- with few exceptions.

For example, using JavaScript:

```
function myFunc(parameter1, parameter2) {
   return 0;
}
let myValue = myFunc(arg1, arg2);
```

Does the area between the parentheses, such as `(parameter1, parameter2)` and `(arg1, arg2)` have a name(s)? There have been times I've been tutoring other budding programmers and grasped for a succinct term to describe these fields, but I've always just had to settle for "that place between the parentheses where the arguments/parameters go". Is there even a name(s)?

What are these called?!?! Any insight is appreciated.

***PLEASE NOTE: I am not asking about HOW arguments are passed, I'm simply asking if there is a term for the field where arguments or parameters are listed. If you're not sure what this means, please see the comments below Matt Cremeens' response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called parameters inside the parentheses of the function definition. When you call the function, such as with `myFunc(arg1, arg2)`, that which is passed inside the parentheses are called arguments. Hope that helps.

I have seen what's inside the parentheses called a [parameter list](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cs113/fall-2000/func/slides/2.html).

Comment: Right, I get that, that's what the individual parameters and arguments are called. I'm looking for if the entire field where parameters or arguments are listed has a name. So like.. `(parameter1, parameter2)` has 2 parameters, but what is that entire statement contained in parentheses where the parameters are listed called?

Comment: I see what you are asking now. See my edit. I suppose you could use the terms argument list and parameter list. That's the best I can come up with at the moment.

Comment: Haha, that works. I've also considered 'parameter field' or 'argument field'. Your response seems to reflect the same lack of certainty I'm suffering from. When programming, we just tend to refer to them as 'the arguments' or 'the parameters', but when teaching a newbie I'd really like to be able to point at the parentheses after a function declaration and say something like "This is the _____, it's where you list the parameters."

Comment: I say you go with parameter list and argument list and this is supported by the link in my answer. Plus I believe that's what I've heard them called before.

Comment: I like it. I like it a lot.

Comment: Great. Hope it helps you at least a little when teaching your students. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the programming language. I deal with VB6 and such. The parameters are actually quite simple once you understand them. Let's say I'm making a report, and I let the user enter FROM and TO date - then I use these two dates to pull up data for the report.

I need to first build a function to do this.......

```
Public Sub BuildClientReport(FromDate as Date, ToDate as Date)
```

--here it does not matter what you call the parameters, as long as you declare them correctly, so since I'm passing in 2 dates, I need to declare them as DATEs.

Now somewhere in the application, you will need to trigger this function to start...

Say, the user enters 2 dates in text boxes called txtFrom.text and txtTo.text. You will use these 2 dates to build the report, so upon calling your BuildClientReport - you will pass these 2 dates from text boxes like this...

```
Call BuildClientReport(Cdate(txtfrom.text), cdate(txtTo.text))
```

This way, the From and To dates will get passed to your function and run the report.

Now that the values have been passed to your BuildClientReport function as FromDate and ToDate - you will be able to use those two variables where you need to reference them.

Comment: Right, I'm not asking about the actual use or workings of passing arguments, I'm just looking for a term. See the comments below Matt's response, that should clear up what's being asked.